# Use latest @material-ui/icons in react-admin without conflicts

Tags: icons, material-ui, react-admin

Are there any best practices on how to use the latest version of `@material-ui/icons` in `react-admin`? I'd want to use a newer icon that is not included in the `1.0.0` version, bundled with `ra-ui-materialui`.

When I try to use a newer version (`3.0.1`) of `@material-ui/icons` in my `package.json` the build sometimes errors with something like this:

> ./node_modules/ra-ui-materialui/node_modules/@material-ui/icons/FilterNone.js
>
> Cannot find module: '@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/interopRequireDefault'. Make sure this package is installed.

When using the same as the shipped version (`^1.0.0`) it builds fine consistently, however, I cannot use icons that were added only recently.

Is there a solution to this dilemma?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same problem

Comment: No, unfortunately I haven't :-( I simply used a different icon... Also, sometimes I found that icons were just renamed and thus also available in the older package, but under a different name.

Comment: Current react-admin is using "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.0". latest meterial UI is conflict with this version. I have used same meterial ui version in my app and I have used latest meterial UI icons( "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2"). it works fine without conflict .

Answer (score 0):

you need to use same the  meterial UI version what is used in react-admin then you can use latest @material-ui/icons version .

Sample package.Json

```
{
  "name": "sample-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.4.2",
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.12",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.8",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.11",
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "firebase": "^5.8.4",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "inflection": "^1.12.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "ra-core": "^2.6.4",
    "ra-data-hasura": "0.0.3",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-admin": "^2.6.2",
    "react-admin-color-input": "^1.0.8",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-redux": "~5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "~4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.5",
    "recompose": "^0.30.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I'm not sure if I understand. So you added `@material-ui/core` as a dependency, with the same version as `react-admin` does, and then you were able to add the latest version of `@material-ui/icons`, too?